# IAB.close() called but is was already closed in TypeScript

Tags: cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I develop an app by using Ionic2 with TypeScript. I am using InAppBrowser plugin in my app. I get "IAB.close() called but is was already closed" warning message in XCode logger and browser don't close when I want to close the browser that I opened. Why do I get this message? Is it possible fix this?

My codes:

```
let browser = InAppBrowser.open("myurl","_system","location=true");
browser.close(); // I get warning message in here.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my issue. I write "_blank" instead of "_system" in the second parameter of the open method. So browser has opened in my app(not use the system browser) and I can close the browser whenever I want.